# Angular tree table

Tags: angular, tree, treetable

I have implemented a tree component which takes in the nested data and renders it recursively on the UI.

```
<tr *ngFor="let node of nodes" style="width:100%">
<td>
    <span *ngIf="node[key].length" [ngClass]="node.isVisible ? 'fa fa-minus col-mr-5':'fa fa-plus col-mr-5'" (click)="toggle(node)">
    </span>
</td>
<td>
    {{node.Name}}
    <div id="expanded-data-nodes" *ngIf="node.isVisible">
        <table id="nested-table">
            <tree-table *ngIf="node[key].length" [key]="key" [data]="node[key]"></tree-table>
        </table>
    </div>
</td>

<td>{{node.Age}}</td>
<td>{{node.Gender}}</td>
<td>{{node.Country}}</td>
```

```
public toggleChildren(data: any) {
    data.isVisible = !data.isVisible;
}
```

I wish to keep all the nodes of the tree table expanded by default.

I tried to remove *ngIf="item.isVisible" from the div and it expands all the rows by default on load, however, the expand collapse does work and I can see all the icons as fa-plus.

Comment: if you work on the same object (data) instead of copying it and setting isVisible on the clone, it is possible that change detection doesn't get triggered.  In `toggleChildren ` put `this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();` and also do `constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {...}`

Comment: Tried this, didnt work

Comment: try this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges() if it doesnt work, your data is probably not getting updated.